# Angular Material data Table Data source

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-material

Im trying to connect backend data to my `dataSource` and I keep getting an error saying: ERROR

```
Error: Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource
```

```
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {

  dataSource: Object; 

  this.data.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
    this.dataSource = data;
  });
```

Comment: The error tells you what type you need to provide: see example here. https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

datesource type is wrong.  don't specify Object. make sure its either : array, Observable, or DataSource.  example:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];

/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
}
```

Comment: Yes I did it that way at first and it works fine. the problem with that way is I can't pass variables from my component to the data source. Like if I have data coming from a backend service

Comment: Other example with observables. The clue is that the datasource shouldnt be defined as an `Object`. https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/ and  https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-material-table/

Comment: i  changed it to this but I don't think its the correct way of doing it:
 dataSource = [];
 this.data.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource = [data];
      console.log(this.dataSource);
    });